# <input> tag in HTML5 does not show until data is fetched from the database

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

In my HTML5 interface developed on NetBeans 7.4, the interface is designed so that the db data is displayed inside  tags for further editing, like this:

```
<td>
<input name="lname" value="<c:out value = '${row.lname}'/>">
</td>
```

The problem is that the  tags are not displayed until the data is fetched. Can this be fixed? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, the servlet container / application server needs to execute the query and output the name before it outputs the text, that's just how it works. You could maybe do something with javascript and have it fetch it somehow, i'm not really sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Just set type="text"

After specifying the type it will be displayed and if no data is there then it will be blank